# IP with apache server and multiple websites

Tags: laravel, apache, server

I am using Apache server with Wamp to have something like this for a dev enviroment:

```
123.45.67.89/website-a/
123.45.67.89/website-b/
```

to get to this point I made 2 aliases that look like this:

```
Alias /website-a "c:/wamp64/www/website-a/public"

<Directory "c:/wamp64/www/website-a/public">
  Options +Indexes +FollowSymLinks +MultiViews
  AllowOverride all
  #Require local
  Require all granted
</Directory>
```

```
Alias /website-b "c:/wamp64/www/website-b/public"

<Directory "c:/wamp64/www/website-b/public">
  Options +Indexes +FollowSymLinks +MultiViews
  AllowOverride all
  #Require local
  Require all granted
</Directory>
```

the issue that I have is basically the fact that the CSS and JS files are not loaded and also when i go to /login there is a 404 error. it appears to reference only the route url and that is the IP 123.45.67.89.

What should I do in order to get this fixed?

Comment: Where are your css and js files located?  They have to be somewhere under the directories you configured.  Same for your /login, somehow you have to tell apache what /login corresponds to.  Look at your logs, it probably says "file not found" or something.  You can put LogLevel to a higher level to get more logs.

Comment: in the public folder. As I am using Laravel or Symfony, inside the public folder there is a index.php and with this file the hole framework is loaded, even the /login. 
Yes, i get 404 even when calling 123.45.67.89/website-a/ for the css and JS files. the website-a part is not seen and I don't know what to do in this case